# Запятая не нужна? Ритуальное обращение или...?

Tags: пунктуация, обращение

*С точки зрения режима такая защита всегда есть нападение, и Пресвятая Дева, как это забавно выглядит: порядочность тихим голосом говорит режиму «нет».* Е.Е. Съянова.

Сначала посчитал её отсутствие опечаткой, но припомнил, что на предыдущих двух сотнях страниц не было замечено ни единой помарки. Чем объяснить, обращение-то очевидное?

Answer (score 2):

**И Пресвятая Дева, и Боже мой** ― выглядят как **междометные выражения** (сращение религиозного обращения и союза), при этом функция союза И сохраняется, а функция обращения отсутствует.

[Розенталь. § 27. Обращения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126).

Не разделяются запятыми **междометные выражения** *Господи помилуй*, *Боже упаси*, *упаси Господи*, *Господи прости*, *слава Тебе Господи* и т. п. (в них нет обращения).

Comment: Речь-то не о том, чтобы разделять запятой, а о том, чтобы обособлять.

Comment: Речь шла о том, чтобы написать: ...и, Пресвятая Дева, как это забавно выглядит... Междометное сочетание обособляется целиком, а внутри его запятая не ставится.

Comment: Междометное сочетание здесь "Пресвятая Дева", а не "и Пресвятая Дева"

Comment: Оформляется как обращение, то есть обособляется: Ох, Пресвятая Дева, и за что мне только эти мучения! [Наталья Александрова. Последний ученик да Винчи (2010)]

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, возможно и так и так. Вот какие варианты "и Боже мой" удалось найти в Нацкорпусе:

1. и, Боже мой,
2. и  Боже мой,
3. и — Боже мой! —

Например:

Дожидаясь поезда, мы стояли, озябшие, усталые, грязные, на зашарканной платформе, когда к брату подошел худенький черненький солдатик в папахе с красной ленточкой, в длинной, не по росту, шинели, и сказал негромко: ― Идите за мной. Чекисты, дежурившие на станции, заинтересовались братом ― может быть, потому, что он действительно походил на офицера со своей плечистостью, твердой осанкой и манерой держать голову по-военному прямо? Он ушел с солдатом, я остался один ― **и Боже мой**, каким подавленным, испуганным, одиноким почувствовал я себя на этой продутой ледяным ветром платформе! 
[В. А. Каверин. Освещенные окна (1974-1976)]

Каждая строчка об оставшихся близких была матери нужна, важна, необходима, письма перечитывались, читались вслух, **и Боже мой**, сколько делалось попыток заинтересовать меня этими письмами, заставить оценить эпистолярный стиль бабушки ― мать неизменно им восхищалась… [Н. И. Ильина. Дороги и судьбы (1957-1985)]

Возможно, это не всегда воспринимается как обращение.

Comment: @shampar Я привел цитату из Каверина так, как она дана в Нацкорпусе: "и боже мой" (*б* строчная)

Comment: Я понимаю. Поправил тихо, чтобы не заострять.

Answer (score 1):

Собрала с миру по нитке:

1) ***[И, частица](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B8)***. 1. Усиливает значение слова, перед которым стоит, для выделения, подчёркивания его. *И какая же ты стала слезливая.*

2) [Усилительные частицы](http://www.netref.ru/v-n-orfografiya-i-punktuaciya-spravochnik-m-izdatele-bulatniko.html?page=17) не имеют ударения, в произношении они сливаются со следующими словами.

3) [Частицы](http://hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-028.htm) *о, ах, а **и др.**,* стоящие перед обращениями, от них не отделяются.

---

А parte: дорого бы я дала, чтобы узнать, что кроется за "и др.".

Answer (score 0):

Разве это обращение? Да простят меня, но это ведь то же самое, что "чёрт побери", например. Неужели это тоже обращение? Другое дело, что такие вставки должны рассматриваться как вводные, членами предложения они не являются и от их изъятия смысл не изменится, поэтому запятыми выделять нужно.

Comment: Простят, конечно. Нет, не то же самое: «Что-то боязно, братишечка... Ну, была не была — Господи, благослови... — Ничуть ему не "боязно"...» Да как же ЭТО изъять без последствий изменения смысла? Вопрос в главном, — к кому обращаются. К чёрту всерьёз никому не придёт в голову обращаться. Так говорить  — обыденная дурная привычка.

Comment: >> *К чёрту всерьёз никому не придёт в голову обращаться.*   Я и говорю - не обращение это. И не только я.